# Passing data between two ViewControllers Problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Hi I have two viewControllers.

NewsViewController

```
#import "SingleViewController.h"
@interface NewsViewController : UIViewController {
}
- (NSString *)getFirstImage:(NSString *)htmlString;
@end
```

and the implementation file:

```
#import "SingleViewController.h"
SingleViewController *singleViewController;

@interface NewsPadViewController () <UIActionSheetDelegate>

- (void)loadSubscriptions;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL wrap;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *items;

@end

@implementation NewsPadViewController
....CODE....
- (void)carouselCurrentItemTapped{
    //[self addSubview:articolo];
    MWFeedItem *item =[reader.feedItems objectAtIndex:[carousel currentItemIndex]];

    NSLog(@"Current Item tappped, index: %d", [carousel currentItemIndex]);

    singleViewController.prova.text=@"CIAO";
    singleViewController.ciao=@"sample";
    [singleViewController.web loadHTMLString:item.summary baseURL:nil];
    NSLog(@"conternutio:");
    NSLog(singleViewController.ciao);
}
```

SingleViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SingleViewController : UIViewController{
    @public
    UIWebView *web;
    UILabel *prova;
    NSString *ciao;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *web;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *prova;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet NSString *ciao;
@end
```

and SingleViewController.m

```
#import "SingleViewController.h"

@implementation SingleViewController
@synthesize web,prova,ciao;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [prova setText:ciao];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Why I can't access from NewsPadViewController at object in SingleViewController? Where is my error? thanks
**UPADATE**

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemTapped{
    //[self addSubview:articolo];
    MWFeedItem *item =[reader.feedItems objectAtIndex:[carousel currentItemIndex]];

    NSLog(@"Current Item tappped, index: %d", [carousel currentItemIndex]);

SingleViewController *singleViewController  = [[SingleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SingleViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];    

    singleViewController.prova.text=@"CIAO";
    singleViewController.ciao=@"sample";
    [singleViewController.web loadHTMLString:item.summary baseURL:nil];
    NSLog(@"conternutio:");
    NSLog(singleViewController.ciao);
    [singleViewController setOpz:@"sample"];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any instantiation of SingleViewController. You have a pointer to it, but I don't see anywhere in your code example where you actually create it.

Somewhere you need something like:

```
if (!singleViewController) {
    singleViewController = [[SingleViewController alloc] init];
}
```

or

```
SingleViewController *singleViewController = [[SingleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SingleView" bundle:nil];
```

or from somewhere else you need to send a message or set an instance variable in NewsViewController that points to an existing instance of SingleViewController.

Comment: Thanks I added the first part of code and with the NSLog(singleViewController.ciao) works! but in the xib doesn't work! The ciao NSString is not loaded in the UILabel and the UIWebView doesn't anything!

Comment: sounds like you didn't set up your outlets in Interface Builder

Comment: The outlets are correct! I try to assign text in the UILabel from the viewDidLoad Method and it works! the problem is only with that sting that I assign in the newsPadViewController! Infact if I try NSLog(ciao) from the viewDidLoad in SingleViewController the string is Empty while if I try to NSLog(SingleViewController.ciao) from NewsPadViewController it contains the text "sample"